# PHP remove character and capitalize

Tags: php

Looking for a little bit of help. I'm using a breadcrumb script and want to do some work on a string.

In this case, I need to remove a '-' from the string as well as capitalize each word. This is what I have:

```
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', $crumb);
$title = ucwords($crumb);
```

But at the moment it does one or the other - I want to combine them (sorry, new to php!)

Many thanks for any help

Paul

Comment: This is really something you should (be able to) figure out yourself. For your own training...

Comment: I agree, because you're almost there. Look carefully at the variables you're working on in both lines..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't referencing the  `$title` variable.

```
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', $crumb); 
$title = ucwords($title); // notice $title instead of $crumb
```

To avoid confusion you could nest the function calls like so...

```
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', ucwords($crumb));
```

Comment: Great - that's exactly what I was looking for....job done!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$title = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $crumb));
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as...

```
$title = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $crumb));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo. It should read:

```
$title = ucwords($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :-)

```
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', $crumb);
$title = ucwords($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', $crumb);
$title = ucwords($crumb);
```

Last line should read:

```
$title = ucwords($title);
```